# Mac OS cannot reach other IPs in local network

Tags: network

My macbook pro was not able to reach internet at my home wifi network. I realized DNS on wifi router IP was not responding. When I set 1.1.1.1 as DNS IP then it was working.

After I found out my gateway IP 192.168.1.1 was not reachable at all. I captured the traffic on en0 wifi interface and saw a strange behavior.

My Wifi IP assigned by DHCP is 192.168.1.33 (Gateway and DNS 192.168.1.1). My macbook is using this IP to reach outside of the local network. But when it reaches the IPs in local network (i.e 192.168.1.1) it uses another IP 192.168.1.13. Since it doesn't reply arp-requests for this IP, wifi router cannot reach back to this IP.

Here is the capture from en0:

```
10:51:08.953368 IP 192.168.1.13 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 59006, seq 0, length 64
10:51:11.895528 IP 192.168.1.33 > 1.1.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 60030, seq 0, length 64
10:51:12.127368 IP 1.1.1.1 > 192.168.1.33: ICMP echo reply, id 60030, seq 0, length 64
```

As a workaround I add this IP 192.168.1.13 as alias to en0 and it starts working.

```
sudo ifconfig en0 alias 192.168.1.13/24 up
```

Any idea where this IP (192.168.1.13) comes from and how can I permanently get rid of this?